# Lookup wont accept converted objectId as foreignField

Tags: mongodb

I'm trying to do a lookup based on an objectId of a collection.

It doesn't seem to accept it's object Id since it needs to be a type `String` but even after conversion it won't work. Is there a way to make the relation with the Id?

```
   [
  {
    '$match': {
      'student': 'something'
    }
  }, {
    '$lookup': {
      'from': 'classrooms', 
      'localField': 'classroom', <----- The same ID as below but already String type
      'foreignField': {
        '$toString': '$_id' <------ This here is the ID that I'm trying to relate to 
      }, 
      'as': 'result'
    }
  }
]
```

Answer (score 0):

### Try one of these 2 suggestions:

1. Either this one, where conversion happens in a previous stage:

```js
[
  {
    '$match': {
      'student': 'something'
    }
  },
  {
    '$toString': '$_id'
  },
  {
    '$lookup': {
      'from': 'classrooms', 
      'localField': 'classroom',
      'foreignField': '_id', 
      'as': 'result'
    }
  }
]
```

2. If it doesn't work, try instead this one:

```js
[
  {
    $match: {
      'student': 'something'
    }
  },
   $addFields: {
      convertedId: { $toString: "$_id" }
   }
  {
    $lookup: {
      'from': 'classrooms', 
      'localField': 'classroom',
      'foreignField': 'convertedId', 
      'as': 'result'
    }
  }
]
```

In all cases, you should not convert during the lookup stage; make it in a dedicated stage.

Comment: neither worked for me, the first one gives a syntax error and after fixing it it pops up a MongoServer error.

The second one returns an empty result array.

Comment: Can you please give me the name of the collection in question? What are you typing before .aggregate